# How to Ensure Painting Under JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paint, jinternalframe

I have a setup where there are several JInternalFrames within a main JFrame. What I want to do is paint some things on the main JFrame but under the JInternalFrame. If I set up the code like

```
public void paint(Graphics graphics){
    try{
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) s.getDrawGraphics();
        super.paint(g);
        super.paintComponents(g);

        //Insert Paint Code Here

        s.show();
        super.repaint();
    }catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

the painted content shows up above the JInternalFrames (which are components under a JDesktopFrame). If I try putting the painting code before `super.paint(g)` or `super.paintComponents(g)`, the painted content does not show up at all. How do I make it so that the painted content shows up, but under the internal frames?

Note: `s` is a BufferStrategy and the class inherits from an abstract JFrame class.

Comment: Don't override `paint`, child components can be painted independently of their parents, which can do all sorts of weird things.  Don't call `show` or `repaint` either, infact, don't do anything that might cause a repaint to be triggered.  `paint` should paint the current state, nothing more.  Calling `super.paintComponents` is pointless and `paint` will have already done this.  `s.getDrawGraphics` also scares the crap out of me, as you seem to be ignoring the system supplied `Graphics`, so I have no idea where you're actually painting to

Comment: `super.paintComponents(g);` Why is that code included?  IT seems to have broken the paint chain..

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: A simpler solution would be to create a custom component, extending from `JPanel` (or `JDesktopPane` in your case) and override it's `paintComponent` and perform your custom painting there, basically ignoring anything else which might be added to it, this way, what ever you paint will be guaranteed to be painted below the `JInternalFrame`s

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to have an understanding into how painting works in Swing, have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

Basically, if you want to paint something under the `JInternalFrame`'s, the place to start is by overriding the `paintComponent` method of the `JDesktopPane`.  The `paintComponent` method is the lowest virtual level in the paint chain, with `paintBorder` and `paintChildren` painted ontop of it

[image: DesktopPane]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                CustomDesktopPane pane = new CustomDesktopPane();
                JInternalFrame inFrm = new JInternalFrame("Ontop", true, true, true, true);
                inFrm.setSize(100, 100);
                inFrm.setLocation(150, 150);
                inFrm.setVisible(true);
                pane.add(inFrm);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class CustomDesktopPane extends JDesktopPane {

        public CustomDesktopPane() {
            setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font").deriveFont(24f));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            String text = "All your base are belong to us";
            Font font = g2d.getFont();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }


}
```